# neo4j cypher convert array/list to string

Tags: neo4j, cypher

One type of edges in my graph has a property called ***roles***. It is an array/list of strings. It is like `["Bill Smoke", "Haskell Moore", "Tadeusz Kesselring", "Nurse Noakes", "Boardman Mephi", "Old Georgie"]`

How can I convert this to a string? I want to join them. With JS, I can do `['asd', '1', '2'].join('')`. I want a similar functionality inside cypher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH REDUCE(mergedString = "",word IN ["Bill Smoke", "Haskell Moore", "Tadeusz Kesselring", "Nurse Noakes", "Boardman Mephi", "Old Georgie"] | mergedString+word+',') as joinedString
RETURN LEFT(joinedString,SIZE(joinedString)-1)
```

REDUCE is the function you are basically looking for . 
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce

Answer (score 9):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) has support for several categories of helper functions, this one included.

When installed, you can use [apoc.text.join()](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/misc/text-functions/#text-functions-split-join) to get the desired result:

```
WITH ["Bill Smoke", "Haskell Moore", "Tadeusz Kesselring", "Nurse Noakes", "Boardman Mephi", "Old Georgie"] as list
RETURN apoc.text.join(list, ' ') as string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH ["Bill Smoke", "Haskell Moore", "Tadeusz Kesselring", "Nurse Noakes", "Boardman Mephi", "Old Georgie"] AS array,
     ';' AS separator
RETURN REDUCE(mergedString = "",item IN array | 
              mergedString
              + CASE WHEN mergedString='' THEN '' ELSE separator END
              + item) AS mergedString
```